# How can I pass over the firewall when I scraping with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

There is a website I constantly read data from pages of this website by sending HTTP requests. I'm sending a request to each page in a loop and the system blocking me for a while when I sent too many requests. So, when I sent any request again to a page to read content after blocking me it's responding an error. What are the solutions to fix this issue?

Comment: You can use proxies to get around the usage limit on your IP address

Comment: I don't know maximum how many times I can use a proxy for thousands of requests but for sure I should push the limits

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably blocking your IP for certain time, as they detect this as abuse.

The best solution for this would be to use proxies for the request.
In this case rotating-proxies would be the best choice.

Let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: Yes, probably it's blocking my IP address and maybe I can solve this issue directly by using a proxy but I'm not sure whether another factor or not. What else can cause this issue and is it entirely solvable in any case? 

If you have any idea about it let me know please!

I will let you know after I tried proxy.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: I'm asking about other possibilities except IP blocking maybe they are blocking my mac address or any information that is outgoing from my HTTP request. If it is blocking many things like my IP address, does using a proxy remove all blocking in this case?

Comment: Please provide more Details.

What kind of Service you want to send requests to?
Show us your code.